How to understand the calculations for the density matrices of a qubit state
From a lecture, I wrote this set of calculations for the entropy of a given qubit state.
What I am unsure of, since it was not shown at the lecture, is how the lecturer came to each of these matrices.
Does anyone have a complete illustrative answer or a link to a full description of the given matrix operations and tensor calculus done here?

Let $|\Phi\rangle^\dagger$ be a qubit state,
$$\rho=\frac56|\Psi^+\rangle\langle\Psi^+|+\frac{1}{24}I_4$$
where the Bell-state is $$|\Psi^+\rangle=\frac{|0 \ 1\rangle+|1
\ 0\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}.$$ In order to calculate its concurrence and the
entanglement of formation, we start with
$\rho$  which is \begin{equation}
     \rho=\begin{pmatrix}
         \frac{11}{24}& 0 & 0 & \frac{5}{12}\\
         0& \frac{1}{24}& 0&0\\
         0&0&\frac{11}{24}&0\\
         \frac{5}{12}&0&0&\frac{11}{24}
     \end{pmatrix} \end{equation}


Then we find  \begin{equation}
    \tilde{\rho}=\rho (\sigma_y\otimes\sigma_y)\rho^\dagger(\sigma_y\otimes\sigma_y)=\begin{pmatrix}
         \frac{221}{576}&0&0&\frac{55}{144}\\
         0&\frac{1}{576}&0&0\\
         0&0&\frac{1}{576}&0\\
         \frac{55}{144}&0&0&\frac{221}{576}
     \end{pmatrix} \end{equation} which has the following eigenvalues $$\lambda_1=\frac{49}{64}, \lambda_2=\frac{1}{576},
 \lambda_3=\frac{1}{576}, \lambda_4=\frac{1}{576}.$$

With Thanks

What is $I_4$ ?

All I remember is that he said something about the identity matrix in 4 dimensions

It's the 4-by-4 identity matrix. For some context, a density matrix should be normalized to have trace one. As such, $\rho_0=I_4/4$ is the maximally-mixed two-qubit density matrix. Hence $\rho=\frac56|\Phi^\dagger\rangle\langle\Phi^\dagger|+\frac16 \rho_0$, i.e., $\rho$ is a mixture of the maximally-mixed state and a pure state.

May this help ? http://wla.berkeley.edu/~cs191/fa14/lectures/lecture23.pdf

@EDX close, but doesn't show calculations with numbers...I already have those formulas

There are multiple steps within this note, including finding the matrix form of $\rho$ and then that of the concurrence $\tilde{\rho}$. Which of these are you struggling with?

all of them. I know only that we need to start with a Bell Basis

The tool fundamental to this computation is the Kronecker product of any two matrices $A,B$ which is defined as
$$A\otimes B:=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}B&\cdots&a_{1n}B\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\a_{m1}B&\cdots&a_{mn}B\end{pmatrix}.$$
In quantum information, for computational basis states the abbreviation $|jk\rangle:=|j\rangle\otimes|k\rangle$ is commonly used. Thus, as an example, your Bell state is represented by the vector
\begin{align*}
|\Psi^+\rangle=\frac{|0 \ 1\rangle+|1
\ 0\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}&=\frac{|0\rangle\otimes| 1\rangle+|1
\rangle\otimes| 0\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt2}\Big( \begin{pmatrix}{\color{blue}1}\\{\color{red}0}\end{pmatrix}\otimes\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}\otimes \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix} \Big)\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt2}\Big( \begin{pmatrix}{\color{blue}1}\cdot 0\\{\color{blue}1}\cdot 1\\{\color{red}0}\cdot 0\\{\color{red}0}\cdot 1\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0\cdot 1\\0\cdot 0\\1\cdot 1\\1\cdot 0\end{pmatrix} \Big)=\frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}
0\\1\\1\\0
\end{pmatrix};
\end{align*}
(I used different colors to indicate which entry from the original entry goes where in the Kronecker product.)
Everything that is left is just basic linear algebra, albeit in a more "quantum info"-formulation: the outer product $|\Psi^+\rangle\langle\Psi^+|$ evaluates to
\begin{align*}
|\Psi^+\rangle\langle\Psi^+|&=\frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}
0\\1\\1\\0
\end{pmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}
0\\1\\1\\0
\end{pmatrix}^\dagger=\frac1{2}\begin{pmatrix}
0\\1\\1\\0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&1&0
\end{pmatrix}=\frac12\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0&0\\
0&1&1&0\\
0&1&1&0\\
0&0&0&0\,.
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
At this point you may notice that this matrix does not match the $4\times 4$ matrix $\rho$ from your question. For that the Bell state $|\Phi^+\rangle=\frac1{\sqrt2}(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)$ would have to be used.
Regardless, these basics (together with the definition of the Pauli matrices) should be enough for you to understand the remaining computations.

Thanks Fredrik! This was very enlightening!  I got this, based on your layout that $\rho$ is
\begin{equation}
\rho=\frac{5}{12}\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0&0\
0&1&1&0\
0&1&1&0\
0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}+\frac{1}{24}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0\
0&1&0&0\
0&0&1&0\
0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}\end{equation} and indeed that lecture was wrong! But what is $\sigma_y$? in
$$
\tilde{\rho}=\rho (\sigma_y\otimes\sigma_y)\rho^\dagger(\sigma_y\otimes\sigma_y)$$

You're welcome! As I wrote/linked to at the end of my post, $\sigma_y$ is the Pauli-y matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}0&-i\i&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Fantastic, this completes the question and answer. This was a great answer.Thanks again
